# Cannot sign commit with exported GPG key from other machine

Tags: linux, git, github, gnupg, gpg-signature

I need help with gpg key in git.
First I export keys from windows with this:

```sh
gpg --output backupkeys.pgp --armor --export-secret-keys --export-options export-backup user@email
```

Then on linux I import this key

```sh
gpg --import backupkeys.pgp
```

and change from unknown to ultimate. So this is how I import this key to linux.
But now I need add gpg key to git, so I do this:

```sh
git config --global user.signingkey mySuperKey
```

but when I can create commit

```
git commit -S -m "Super Commit"
```

I have this output

```sh
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I don't know where is problem.

Comment: Does gpg work by itself? What happens if you run `echo hello world | gpg -sa -u user@email`?

Comment: Probably no
`gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying exporting new GPG keys and later import. I found answare for this problem.

```sh
echo hello world | gpg -sa -u user@email
```

if I try this don't show this:

```
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: [stdin]: clear-sign failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

So all what I need to do is this:

```sh
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```